# Does mega/primal/ex raid count towards legendary achievement?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is the legendary achievement medal solely be earned by legendary silver egg raids?

What about ex-raid, primal or mega raid?

Does mega/primal/ex raid count towards legendary achievement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mega/primal raids, it depends on the specific mega. Only the legendary Megas - Latias, Latios, Kyogre, and Groudon being the four to be released so far - count towards the Battle Legend medal. All other Mega raids so far have counted towards the Champion medal. In addition to this distinction, the legendary Mega raids are a Tier 6 difficulty raid, versus the regular Tier 4 mega raids.

EX Raids no longer exist, but they counted towards the Battle Legend medal while they were available. The feature that replaced them, Elite Raids, also count towards the Battle Legend medal.